# Two level authentication for ssh

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, openssh, one-time-password

I am trying to implement a two level authentication for a OPEN SSH, first of which is a ssh public key and private key authentication and second one is an OTP authentication, foe which i am using google authenticator. Everything works as expected till first level of authentication and generating an OTP and feeding it as input for second level. 
I'm stuck here.. if the OTP matches i am executing the command to give user the shell.I'm not clear what am i supposed to do if it doesn't match as first level of authentication is already done. How should i log the user out of the shell...?

Below is the code:

```
if(validate(secretkey,otp)):
    print("OTP Matched")
    try:
        check_call(['/bin/bash'])
    except Exception,e:
        print("Error Giving Shell to user: "+str(e))
else:
try:
    check_call(['/bin/bash'])
    check_call(['exit'])
    except Exception,e:
        print("Error Exiting the user: "+str(e))
    print("Authentication Failed")
```

Comment: why are you trying to implement something that is already there and exists? It would be easier to use `pam` module for google authenticator.
Anyway you are looking for some `exit` call.

Comment: To my knowledge ssh key auth and PAM (OTP) can not be combined. So obviously you are trying to run a this script after login, which checks the OTP. But then you should spawn a shell!. I.e. call this script as login shell and in this script you should call a shell.
Do not exit on error. If you exit, then the user should be logged out. You can achieve this, when using the script as the login shell.
But this will probably not work for scp.
So you should think about, if you should not use OTP with PAM.